# How to run a script from a module without change import?

Tags: python

I want to run a script inside module that I created but I have a import problem.

I have a `Main.py`, a folder Data with `Regression.py` inside and another folder Image with `Modifier.py` inside.

Like this:

```
Main.py
Data/
   | __init__.py
   | Regression.py
   | Image/
      | __init__.py
      | Modifier.py
```

Main import Regression and Regression import Modifier.

Inside Regression.py I have `import Image` 
but went I run Main.py I have the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'`

But if I use `from Data import Image` no error when I run main but I have a error when I run Regression.py:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Image' from 'Data'`

The only solution I found is to do this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import Image
elif __name__ == "Data.Regression":
    from Data import Image
```

This solution works but it will be problematic if I create another module that uses Data.

Please, there is anoter solution ?

Main.py

```py
import Data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = Data.Regression.LoadTest()
    print("End")
```

Data/__init__.py

```py
__all__ = ["Classification", "Regression"]
from . import Classification
from . import Regression
```

Data/Regression.py

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import Image
elif __name__ == "Data.Regression":
    from Data import Image

import numpy as np

def LoadSet():
    #load img
    data = Image.Modifier.Modify(img)
    # other part of code
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Regression.LoadSet()
    # test code of Regression
    print("End")
```

Data/Image/__init__.py

```py
__all__ = ["Modifier"]
from . import Modifier
```

Data/Image/Modifier.py

```py
import numpy as np

def Modify(img):
# modify my image
    return img
```

Comment: I found the problem, first I need to execute Regression.py with the parent folder as environnement variable to just have `from Data import Image` and secondly, rename  Data.py because this confuse Regression.py which try to find Image inside Data.py instead of module Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use relative import:

`from . import Image`

or type full path to the module you're importing, relative to `__main__`:

`import Data.Image`

And please stick to the convention and name your modules in lowercase.

Comment: Yes but am I obliged to use an if? because I want to run 2 `__main__`, one in `Main.py` and the other in `Regression.py`

Comment: Yes, if you directly run a module from a package, it is no longer aware what package it's in.